# How to populate this table

Tags: sql

I have a table named table_1. It is defined below as

```
CREATE table_1 (
    start text,
    end text, 
    cost text
    );
```

I need to populate table_1 from table_2, while table_2 only has the first two columns.

```
insert into table_1 (start, end) 
select start, end
from table_2
```

How can I add the 3rd column for each row?

I am using sqlite. The values for the 3rd column for all rows from table_2 are "type_2".

Thanks.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: What values should you put in  3rd  column ?

Comment: I am using sqlite. The values for the 3rd column for all rows from table_2 are "type_2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends what is supposed to be in the third field.
There could be ZERO or a difference between start and end, or something else

`insert into table_1 (start, end, cost) 
select start, end, "type_2"
from table_2`

P.S. However, type Text for all these fields is probably inappropriate.
I might do something like this:

`CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    start DATETIME,
    end DATETIME, 
    cost_seconds INT
    );`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in this example. the value for cost is independent of  the values for start and end.

Comment: So? Instead of "end - start" put value of "ZERO" or any other independent value.

Comment: other independent value. I would like to give a value "type_2" for for the rows populated from "table_2"

Comment: Edited the answer, do you like this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer !